# Constructor in class cannot be applied to give types error

Tags: java, inheritance, methods

Im trying to write a program using inheritance, that will print the most cost effective broadband/telephone package based on the users usage. (so the basic idea is that the user enters the amount of minutes and MB of broadband required and the program prints the closest match in terms of usage.)
I keep getting the errors "Constructors premium Account in class premiumAccount cannot be applied to given types"

code as follows:
Subclass 2:

```
   public class PremiumAccount extends IntermediateAccount {

  // ------------FIELDS--------

public double dayPhone;
public double eveningPhone;
public double numberChannels;
public double broadband;
public double extraBroadband;
public double packageCost;
public double totalCost;


  // -------CONSTRUCTORS

public PremiumAccount( double dPhone, double evPhone, double       noChannels, double bband, double pCost, double extBroadband, double totCost){
  super(dPhone, evPhone, noChannels, bband, pCost, extBroadband,     totCost);
dayPhone = dPhone;
eveningPhone = evPhone;
numberChannels = noChannels;
broadband = bband;
packageCost = pCost;
extraBroadband = extBroadband;
totalCost = totCost;
 };
```

SuperClass:

```
 public class BasicAccount {
 // ------------FIELDS--------

protected double dayPhone;
protected double eveningPhone;
protected double numberChannels;
protected double broadband;
protected  double extraBroadband;
protected double packageCost;
protected double totalCost;

// -------CONSTRUCTORS

protected BasicAccount( double dPhone, double evPhone, 
double noChannels, double bband, double pCost, 
double extBroadband, double totCost){
 dayPhone = dPhone;
eveningPhone = evPhone;
numberChannels = noChannels;
broadband = bband;
packageCost = pCost;
extraBroadband = extBroadband;
totalCost = totCost;
 };
```

problem in user class:
     // Call constructors with the correct value

```
newPremiumAccount = new PremiumAccount(dayphoneInput, 
evenphoneInput,  broadusageInput);
```

error indicates error is at 
newPremiumAccount = new PremiumAccount(dayphoneInput, evenphoneInput, 
                    ^
broadusageInput);

Sorry if thats too much code! The code isnt finished yet i was just testing how i would call the subclasses in the main class but i cant seem to get around the above error!

Comment: you missed arguements in your constructor.

Comment: under which class?

Comment: when you call `new PremiumAccount(dayphoneInput, evenphoneInput, ^ broadusageInput);`, does not match expected constructor `PremiumAccount( double dPhone, double evPhone, double       noChannels, double bband, double pCost, double extBroadband, double totCost)`

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.